# ListBox filled with binding doesn't select item on click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, selection

I'm trying to use a ListBox to choose an entry and then display a picture belonging to this selected entry. But just at the beginning I got my first problem: filling the ListBox with binding is working, but if I click on one line in my running program, it doesn't select the line. I can just see the highlighted hover effect, but not select a line. Any ideas what my mistake could be?

This is my XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="entrySelection" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=entryItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="335" Margin="428,349,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="540" FontSize="24"/>
```

And in MainWindow.xaml.cs I'm filling the ListBox with entries:

```
private void fillEntrySelectionListBox()
    {
        //Fill listBox with entries for active user
        DataContext = this;
        entryItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
        foreach (HistoryEntry h in activeUser.History)
        {
            var cbItem = new ComboBoxItem();
            cbItem.Content = h.toString();
            entryItems.Add(cbItem);
        }
        this.entrySelection.ItemsSource = entryItems;
        labelEntrySelection.Text = "Einträge für: " + activeUser.Id;

        //show image matching the selected entry
        if (activeUser.History != null)
        {
            int index = entrySelection.SelectedIndex;
            if (index != -1 && index < activeUser.History.Count)
            {
                this.entryImage.Source = activeUser.History[index].Image;
            }
        }
    }
```

So I can see my ListBox correctly filled, but not select anything - so I can't go on with loading the picture matching the selected entry.
I'm still quite new to programming, so any help would be great :)

---

EDIT: If someone takes a look at this thread later: here's the - quite obvious -solution

XAML now looks like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="entrySelection" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=entryItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="335" Margin="428,349,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="540" FontFamily="Siemens sans" FontSize="24">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Code behind to fill it:

```
//Fill listbox with entries for selected user
DataContext = this;
entryItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
foreach (HistoryEntry h in selectedUser.History)
{
    var lbItem = new DataItem(h.toString());
    entryItems.Add(lbItem);
}
this.entrySelection.ItemsSource = entryItems;
labelEntrySelection.Text = "Einträge für: " + selectedUser.Id;
```

And new Class DataItem:

```
class DataItem
{
    private String text;

    public DataItem(String s)
    {
        text = s;
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get 
        { 
            return text; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filling it with ComboBoxItem, which is not relevant to the ListBox, and also wrong by definition.

You need to have the ObservableCollection filled with data items.

Meaning, make a class that contains the data you want to store, and the ListBox will generate a ListBoxItem automatically per data item.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/

Comment: Oh, thanks for this hint - that's a copy and paste mistake. I'll try it :)

Comment: yes, now it works - I'm feeling quite stupid now ^^ thanks for the help :)